# Ubuntu 17.04 doesnt recognize Geforce GTX 950M

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 17.04

Ubuntu 17.04 doesn't recognize my graphics card. Under 16.04 everything worked.

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
```

Only intel graphics is listed, nvidia missing. BIOS settings dont allow to select graphics card or disable NVIDIA.

```
$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] HD Graphics 530
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

Any suggestion, lost here :(

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: There is no Nvidia adapter.